# Deletion of a directory with System.IO.Directory.Delete

Tags: c#, .net, file, io, directory

I have a c# application, in which i have to delete a directory:

```
 if (buttonName == "Supprimer projet")
            {
                if (url != null)
                {
                    proj.DeleteDirectory(proj.GetProjectsId(url));
                    var path = Path.Combine(@"C:\Projets", url);
                    try
                    {
                        Directory.Delete(path);
                    }
                    catch { }
                    return RedirectToAction("Gestion", "Admin");
                }
            }
```

but i have this exception `the directory is not empty \r\n` .

What is the reason of this error? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the overload that accepts a boolean as the second parameter and pass true. That will recursively delete all files and directories in the directory. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx

**Directory.Delete Method (String, Boolean)**:

```
public static void Delete(
    string path,
    bool recursive
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Directory.Delete(dirname, true)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx) to recursively delete a directory.

However, this will still fail if you don't have the rights to delete any of the files or folders (and read-only files will also cause you problems).

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Directory.Delete(path, true);
```

From [Directory.Delete Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx), the second bool flag is

> true to remove directories, subdirectories, and files in path;
>   otherwise, false.

Answer (score 2):

Use version of Directory.Delete with a second bool parameter (recursive) set to true

```
Directory.Delete(path, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
Directory.Delete(@"c:\somedirectory", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call this function with dir name. It will delete that dir including contents.

```
static void DirDelete(string sDir)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
            {
                foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
                {
                    File.Delete(f);
                }
                DirDelete(d);
                Directory.Delete(d);
            }
            Directory.Delete(sDir);
        }
        catch (System.Exception excpt)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't implement something yourself that is already provided by the framework (see other answers). Especially not something that spams some debugging text to the console.

Comment: When I saw the question no is answered and I tried this in my system and posted. Yeah, after posting it I found many answered that. Honestly, I am not aware that is already supported by framework.

BTW, I removed debugging text.

Comment: @Ganeshkumar In my test campaign, Directory.Delete(path, true) sucks all the time, but your function that I shamelessly copied does the thing stably.

Comment: @AlexKonnen ha ha... don't feel bad. I contribute very less to the community. Most of the time I copy shamelessly from others :)